# Running from inside or outside a PHP object

Tags: php, oop, scope

I'm using overflow __set and __get methods and I would like to be able to emulate private / public class variables.

I am sure the answer for this is already out there, but I've been digging and can't find a thing. Let me just try to show an example of along the lines of what I'm trying to do.

```
<?php
class Person
{
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->whereami();
    }

    public function whereami()
    {
         if (method_called_inside_class()) {
             return 'private';
         } else {
             return 'public';
         }
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->test(); // 'private'
$person->whereami(); // 'public'
```

What I would like is a different functionality for a method **when called within an object vs. being called from outside**. I know I can just add a another argument to signal a change in behavior, or create another function. But if what I'm trying to do here is in some way possible instead of those other two options, that would be awesome!

Comment: debug_backtrace should give you the information you need, but even wanting to do this is a sign of a major design problem. It should probably just be two different methods.

Comment: You can make a private function and use `__call` method. But I am curious at what scene this is needed...

Comment: Why do you care who the caller is ?

Comment: This seems like a good way to confuse people who try to use your function.

Comment: I'm using overflow __set and __get methods and I would like to be able to emulate private / public class variables.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question why you need this. You have *one* public interface which acts as the public interface. Internally you can do whatever you want. `public`/`private` is about *who can access it*, not *how it behaves*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to use object variables that are not explicitly defined in the code but can be used. And for some of them the magic getter and setter shall return the variable and for others they should not.

Assuming this, you could solve the problem partially by doing the following thing. Inside the class you would have to access the variables directly with `$this->data['name'];`. I know that it is not 100% of what you are looking for but I don't think you can actually differentiate between a call from within the class and from outside the class. The function you used doesn't even exist.

```
<?php

class MagicGetterSetter {
    // contains the variables
    private $data = array();

    private $publicVariables = array('test', 'foo', 'hierarchy');

    public function __get($name) {
        if (isset($this->data[$name])) {
            if (in_array($name, $this->publicVariables)) {
                return $this->data[$name];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if (in_array($name, $this->publicVariables)) {
            $this->data[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        if (in_array($name, $this->publicVariables)) {
            return isset($this->data[$name]);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```